# How to get the total weeks with dates for the given month in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Respected Experts,

According to our company requirement we need following weeks details for any month

e.g.
If month is **April** and year is **2017** than the query result should be

```
weeknumber     startdate     enddate 
    1         01-04-2017   01-04-2017    
    2         02-04-2017   08-04-2017
    3         09-04-2017   15-04-2017
    4         16-04-2017   22-04-2017
    5         23-04-2017   29-04-2017
    6         30-04-2017   30-04-2017
```

With the search I am only able to count the weeks in the month but I need start and enddate it should be start from Sunday to Saturday.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What have you tried till now? Please post

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has not demonstrated any effort.

Comment: Weeknumber 3 twice?

Comment: Can you describe the rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want a function to return the weeks of a month for one month then this would do what you want:

```
create function dbo.udf_weeks_of_month (@fromdate date) 
returns table with schemabinding as return (
with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @fromdate )+1, 0))) 
    [DateValue]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto
)
select 
    WeekOfMonth = row_number() over (order by datepart(week,DateValue))
  , WeekStart   = min(DateValue)
  , WeekEnd     = max(DateValue)
from dates
group by datepart(week,DateValue)
);
```

and calling it like so:

```
set datefirst 7;
select 
    WeekOfMonth
  , WeekStart 
  , WeekEnd   
from dbo.udf_weeks_of_month('20170401');
```

returns:

```
+-------------+------------+------------+
| WeekOfMonth | WeekStart  |  WeekEnd   |
+-------------+------------+------------+
|           1 | 2017-04-01 | 2017-04-01 |
|           2 | 2017-04-02 | 2017-04-08 |
|           3 | 2017-04-09 | 2017-04-15 |
|           4 | 2017-04-16 | 2017-04-22 |
|           5 | 2017-04-23 | 2017-04-29 |
|           6 | 2017-04-30 | 2017-04-30 |
+-------------+------------+------------+
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/FSA98744 (note: rextester reformats the dates)

---

This can be handled easily with calendar table instead of a function.

Reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops 2- Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in SQL Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)
- [TSQL Function to Determine Holidays in SQL Server - Tim Cullen](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1537/tsql-function-to-determine-holidays-in-sql-server/)
- [F_TABLE_DATE - Michael Valentine Jones](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519)

Comment: Thank you very much Sir It is Exactly we are looking for !

Comment: @SqlZim: Your function works when OP pass 01042017 i.e first day of the month? what happens if OP provide any date of the month?

Comment: @PareshJ It will return the weeks of the month starting from the date passed as `@fromdate`.  If you need to pass in any date of a month and get all weeks for the month, the `top` can be modified to use `dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @fromdate), 0)` for the first date parameter of the `datediff()`. Or the call to the function can be modified to use `...dbo.udf_weeks_of_month(dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, '20170402'), 0));`

Comment: the holiday function it not by Aaron Bertrand

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Whoops, updated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it (it doesn't rely on set datefirst):

```
-- can be any date within the month
DECLARE @d date = '2017-04-01'
SET @d = dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,@d),0)
;WITH CTE(dat) as
(
  SELECT top(datediff(d, @d, dateadd(mm,1, @d)))
    cast(dateadd(d, row_number() over(order by (SELECT null))-1, @d) as date)
  FROM
    (values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) s(n),
    (values(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n)
)
SELECT 
 datediff(week, @d,dat)+1 wk,
 min(dat) startdate,
 max(dat) enddate
FROM CTE
GROUP BY datediff(week, @d,dat)
```

Result:

```
wk  startdate   enddate
1   2017-04-01  2017-04-01
2   2017-04-02  2017-04-08
3   2017-04-09  2017-04-15
4   2017-04-16  2017-04-22
5   2017-04-23  2017-04-29
6   2017-04-30  2017-04-30
```